# Multithreading vs multiprocessing

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am new to this kind of programming and need your point of view.

I have to build an application but I can't get it to compute fast enough. I have already tried Intel TBB, and it is easy to use, but I have never used other libraries.

In multiprocessor programming, I am reading about OpenMP and Boost for the multithreading, but I don't know their pros and cons.

In C++, when is multi threaded programming advantageous compared to multiprocessor programming and vice versa?Which is best suited to heavy computations or launching many tasks...? What are their pros and cons when we build an application designed with them? And finally, which library is best to work with?

Comment: In a multiprocessor machine using a thread library like boost will take advantage of the available cores. You also can have multiple threads on one processor which can be interleavened with technologies such as hyperthreading in Pentium 4.  Did you mean multi-process and a distributed system or multi-threading? You can do both actually but the nature of threads is get parallelism regardless of processor.

FYI boost is based off posix threads as far as I know and I find it quite easy to use. Also the new C++0x standard will include thread support native to the language.

Comment: What do you think about Boost and Intel TBB? It is faster than Intel TBB? Or I should go for Intel if I have an intel processor?

Comment: Intel TBB has the advantage in some areas where it provides optimized parallel primitives like parallel for-loops, etc., that aid in the creation of parallel scatter-gather style algorithms on Intel processors, as well as other parallel computations. Boost threads is mainly a cross-platform threading package that will run on many types of hardware and OS platforms.  You if you need certain parallel computational primitives though, Boost threads doesn't directly provide that, you would have to code them up yourself.  So you could look at TBB as being at a higher-level of abstraction than Boost.

Comment: Never used Intel TBB so can't say but your performance will mostly depend on your implementation. I choose boost for the cross platform nature so that asynchronous task server could be distributed across linux or windows machines. I prefer boost::thread over Windows threads, or QThread which is the only other threading I've used. The TBB wiki article makes it sound like it is higher level than boost so it may be easier to implement initially depending on what level of thread control you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks

Comment: One important difference: when a thread crash, the process stops. When a thread hang, either the process stops or you kill it and you've got to worry about the state of memory. This means that multi-processing can be more robust. For servers, for example, it is "normal" to have at least a monitoring/launcher process separate from the actual process executing.

Comment: A proper answer to your question depends on the nature of the problem to be solved & the platform you're targeting.  There are whole classes of problems that can't be sped up at all by parallel programming.  If you can expand on your question a bit, it'll definitely help you get more usable, concrete answers.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Multithreading means exactly that, running multiple threads.  This can be done on a uni-processor system, or on a multi-processor system.

On a single-processor system, when running multiple threads, the actual observation of the computer doing multiple things at the same time (i.e., multi-tasking) is an illusion, because what's really happening under the hood is that there is a software scheduler performing time-slicing on the single CPU.  So only a single task is happening at any given time, but the scheduler is switching between tasks fast enough so that you never notice that there are multiple processes, threads, etc., contending for the same CPU resource.

On a multi-processor system, the need for time-slicing is reduced.  The time-slicing effect is still there, because a modern OS could have hundred's of threads contending for two or more processors, and there is typically never a 1-to-1 relationship in the number of threads to the number of processing cores available.  So at some point, a thread will have to stop and another thread starts on a CPU that the two threads are sharing.  This is again handled by the OS's scheduler.  That being said, with a multiprocessors system, you *can* have two things happening at the same time, unlike with the uni-processor system.

In the end, the two paradigms are really somewhat orthogonal in the sense that you will need multithreading whenever you want to have two or more tasks running asynchronously, but because of time-slicing, you do not necessarily need a multi-processor system to accomplish that.  If you are trying to run multiple threads, and are doing a task that is highly parallel (i.e., trying to solve an integral), then yes, the more cores you can throw at a problem, the better.  You won't necessarily need a 1-to-1 relationship between threads and processing cores, but at the same time, you don't want to spin off so many threads that you end up with tons of idle threads because they must wait to be scheduled on one of the available CPU cores.  On the other hand, if your parallel tasks requires some sequential component, i.e., a thread will be waiting for the result from another thread before it can continue, then you may be able to run more threads with some type of barrier or synchronization method so that the threads that need to be idle are not spinning away using CPU time, and only the threads that need to run are contending for CPU resources.

Comment: Dang you type fast! I'll just add my two cents as a comment.

Comment: All comment is great for me :)
@ Jason, so thread is designed to programme many big part of the app and do their job no?

Comment: A thread can be used for a task ... that task can be anything.  It could be something that runs the entire duration of your program, such as a network daemon that would "listen" for connections on a socket and then spin off more threads to manage those connections. A thread can also used for a small task like solving an iteration of an integral which is a highly parallel task.

Comment: So you use multithread to everything and everywhere in your programme? When I should stop to divize my programme in threads? And It's not better to use the multiproc libraries to do big calculs (Intel TBB, OpenMP..)?

Comment: Those types of libraries can help with computational tasks since they are a higher-level abstraction over raw threading libraries like Boost, pthreads, etc., but whenever you need to-do multiple things at the "same time" (I say that with quotes since on a uni-processor system it's an illusion), you're going to need a separate thread for each task.  There are a lots of times though where you're writing utilities that only do one thing, and so you won't need threads for those types of applications. For instance, command-line apps like `grep`, `sed`, `cp`, etc., aren't multi-threaded.

Answer (score 27):

There are a few important points that I believe should be added to the excellent answer by @Jason.

First, multithreading is not always an illusion even on a single processor - there are operations that do not involve the processor. These are mainly I/O - disk, network, terminal etc. The basic form for such operation is ***blocking*** or ***synchronous***, i.e. your program waits until the operation is completed and then proceeds. While waiting, the CPU is switched to another process/thread.

if you have anything you can do during that time (e.g. background computation while waiting for user input, serving another request etc.) you have basically two options:

- **use asynchronous I/O**: you call a *non-blocking* I/O providing it with a *callback function*, telling it "call this function when you are done". The call returns immediately and the I/O operation continues in the background. You go on with the other stuff.
- **use multithreading**: you have a dedicated thread for each kind of task. While one waits for the blocking I/O call, the other goes on.

Both approaches are difficult programming paradigms, each has its pros and cons.

- with async I/O the logic of the program's logic is less obvious and is difficult to follow and debug. However you avoid *thread-safety* issues.
- with threads, the challange is to write [thread-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) programs. Thread safety faults are nasty bugs that are quite difficult to reproduce. Over-use of locking can actually lead to degrading instead of improving the performance.

(coming to the multi-processing)

Multithreading made popular on Windows because manipulating processes is quite  heavy on Windows (creating a process, context-switching etc.) as opposed to threads which are much more lightweight (at least this was the case when I worked on Win2K).

On Linux/Unix, processes are much more lightweight. Also (AFAIK) threads on Linux are implemented actually as a kind of processes internally, so there is no gain in context-switching of threads vs. processes. However, you need to use some form of IPC (inter-process communications), as shared memory, pipes, message queue etc.

On a more lite note, look at the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6),  which declares "Threads are evil"! :)

Comment: There's also a third option, multiplexing the I/O through select()/poll()/etc.  That can be safer than multithreading and easier to understand than asynchronous I/O.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the first question:
The best approach is to just use multithreading techniques in your code until you get to the point where even that doesn't give you enough benefit.  Assume the OS will handle delegation to multiple processors if they're available.

If you actually are working on a problem where multithreading isn't enough, even with multiple processors (or if you're running on an OS that isn't using its multiple processors), then you can worry about discovering how to get more power.  Which might mean spawning processes across a network to other machines.

I haven't used TBB, but I have used IPP and found it to be efficient and well-designed.  Boost is portable.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that the Flow-Based Programming ( http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp ) paradigm is a naturally multiprogramming/multiprocessing approach to application development.  It provides a consistent application view from high level to low level. The Java and C# implementations take advantage of all the processors on your machine, but the older C++ implementation only uses one processor.  However, it could fairly easily be extended to use BOOST (or pthreads, I assume) by the use of locking on connections.  I had started converting it to use fibers, but I'm not sure if there's any point in continuing on this route. :-)  Feedback would be appreciated.  BTW The Java and C# implementations can even intercommunicate using sockets.